# Pandas fillna by "join" of another df?

Tags: python, pandas, join, fillna

I have 2 DFs, one with IDs and one with entries. Basically:

```
ID    Val
1     111
2     222
3     333
```

And another one where some of the Vals are missing:

```
ID    Val   Other
1     111   123
1     NaN   3
1     111   5
2     222   3553
2     NaN   58
2     222   321
3     NaN   456
```

What I'd like to do is to fill the missing values in Val on the second df with the Val values in the first df. So the outcome should be:

```
ID    Val   Other
1     111   123
1     111   3
1     111   5
2     222   3553
2     222   58
2     222   321
3     NaN   456
```

How can I achieve this? I've seen a similar use case but from within the same df. When I try this, I get an error bc. the dimensions of my df are mismatched of course.

So the question is, how can I fill my NaN values by a "join"?

Comment: You don't need the first dataframe, if the values are sorted by ID in the second, just do `df.ffill()`

Comment: Is `ID` index or a column?

Comment: @mozway But what if he has `NaN` in the first (or only) row of the`ID`?

Comment: @Aryerez it's a column!

Comment: @mozway yes I do, there are some cases where th Val is not present in the second df at all.

Comment: @Ite__ then `df2.groupby('ID').transform('first')`

Comment: @mozway okay for the third time:  This does not take into account the case where the first or only Val is NaN in the second df. Neither ffill nor bfill accounts for that case.

Comment: @Ite__ you should provide **all** information from the beginning, anyway, check my current updated answer it works with both dfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataframes are df1 and df2:

```
df2.groupby('ID').apply(lambda s: s.fillna(df1.set_index('ID')['Val'][s.name]))
```

output:

```
     Val  Other
0  111.0    123
1  111.0      3
2  111.0      5
3  222.0   3553
4  222.0     58
5  222.0    321
```

Comment: This does not take into account the case where the first or only Val is NaN in the second df.

Comment: I think you need both `ffill` and `bfill`

Comment: @ThePyGuy This still does not take into account the case where the only Val is NaN in the second df.

Comment: @lte__, I think this answer can still be used, all you need to do is to separate out the rows that don't meet your criteria, and then concatenate later.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You can merge and use `np.where`:

```
vals = df2.merge(df1, on=['ID'], how='left', suffixes=['_',''])['Val']
df2['Val'] = np.where(df2['Val'].isna(), vals, df2['Val'])
```

Speed: *1.87 ms ± 29.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)*

---

**Solution 2:**

Create a mapping-dictionary and map the values to the ID.

```
dct = df1.set_index('ID').to_dict()['Val']
df2.loc[df2['Val'].isna(), 'Val'] = df2['ID'].map(dct)
```

Speed: *1.94 ms ± 66.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)*

---

---

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'Val': {0: 111, 1: 222}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2}, 'Val': {0: 111.0, 1: np.nan, 2: 111.0, 3: 222.0, 4: np.nan, 5: 222.0}, 'Other': {0: 123, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 3553, 4: 58, 5: 321}})
```

---

**Output:**

```
   ID    Val  Other
0   1  111.0    123
1   1  111.0      3
2   1  111.0      5
3   2  222.0   3553
4   2  222.0     58
5   2  222.0    321
```

Comment: @mozway, thanks and same for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` the first `df` into the second, and than use `combine_first` to fill the `NaN`s:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1.rename({'Val': 'TrueVal'}, axis=1), how='left')
df2['Val'] = df2['Val'].combine_first(df2['TrueVal'])
df2.drop('TrueVal', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Test data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

    a = pd.DataFrame({"ID": {0: 1, 1: 2}, "Val": {0: 111, 1: 222}})
    b = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "ID": {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2},
            "Val": {0: 111.0, 1: np.NaN, 2: 111.0, 3: 222.0, 4: np.NaN, 5: 222.0},
            "Other": {0: 123, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 3553, 4: 58, 5: 321},
        }
    )
```

Then I just use merge:

```
b.merge(a, on="ID")
```

Output:

```
   ID  Val_x  Other  Val_y
0   1  111.0    123    111
1   1    NaN      3    111
2   1  111.0      5    111
3   2  222.0   3553    222
4   2    NaN     58    222
5   2  222.0    321    222
```

Clean up the dataframe with:

```
c = b.merge(a, on="ID").drop("Val_x", axis=1).rename(columns={"Val_y": "Val"})
```

Comment: This also works with your updated example. And I guess you expect the last row ID=3 the Val to be 333?